Is finding the best permutation an NP-Complete problem?
We have a matrix $M$ of size $n$ by $n$ where
$M[i][j] \ge 0$ and $M[i][i] = 0$.
We want to create a permutation of integers $[1,\dots,N]$, like $\langle P_1, P_2,\dots,P_n \rangle$, such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=i}^{N} M[P_i][P_j]
$$
is maximized.
Of course we can try a greedy algorithm to create the permutation $P$ step by step, but what I am looking for at this time is whether this problem is NP-Complete or not. And if so, is there any approximation known for it?
For Fun: Here is what ChatGPT think about it.
Edit1. The problem can be described as:
We have n soccer teams. These teams played some random matches against each other (Team 1 could just have one game against Team 2  while Team 3 having 100 games against Team 4, etc). Entry $M[i][j]$ represents how many times team $i$ won team $j$. We want to find a ranking $P$, for the teams, such that it maximizes the stated summation (which our definition of how well the ranking is).

If I understand the question correctly, then this seems to be essentially Directed Feedback Vertex Set also known as Maximum Acyclic Subgraph. The summation is over forward arcs for the ordering implied by the permutation, so if the aim is to maximize the sum then we directly get Maximum Acyclic Subgraph, if we want to minimize the sum, then the solution ordering is the reverse of an optimal one for Maximum Acyclic Subgraph.

@ChristianKomusiewicz The problem does not require for the transformed graph to be Acyclic.

Please don't use "Edit1. more information".  Instead, please revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  What ChatGPT thinks is irrelevant and can be deleted.

As @ChristianKomusiewicz noted, this is the Maximum Weighted Acyclic Subgraph problem. OP should check the definitions and verify that this is indeed a correct interpretation. Maximum Weighted Acyclic Subgraph is used in ranking problems.
